# PDF reader with text wrapping

Tags: pdf

Is there any PDF reader in the market that has text wrap functionality?
What I'm talking about is the way text wraps when you zoom-in on a webpage.

Most of the PDFs are meant to be read on a computer monitor, so a line of text in a PDF document is too long for a small phone screen. And scrolling horizontally for each line is too much of a pain.

Comment: Could we re-open this? It seems like a good question to me.

Answer (score 7):

I am pretty sure [Mantano Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Mantano%20SAS) and [ezPDF](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Unidocs%20Inc.) do this as well. I recommend the former though.

Comment: Mantano Reader has the text wrapping feature I was looking for. Thanks for the suggestion @Ayman

Comment: Than, why didn't you accept his answer/ Doing so would help others who read this question in future.

Answer (score 2):

[Adobe's Reader](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.adobe.reader) for Android has the Text reflow feature that you're looking for.

Comment: Adobe's Reader has one major problem: it shows current page number in top left corner for a few secs when page switching, which disrupts your reading flow (you have to wait to see the text behind the page number); they should have put the number on the bottom of the screen. I also don't like the way it splits a single page in multiple pages instead of creating one long column per page through which you could scroll vertically.

Comment: I have just installed Adobe Acrobat DC but I can't find the text wrapping option.

Answer (score 0):

The viewer that's part of ThinkFree Office has a "reading view" that does this, and it's easy to toggle between that and the regular page view.